Vertex deletion and reconstruction in MST: boundedness of new degrees
I came across the following question related to graph theory as part of a research in statistics that I am working on.
Consider an Euclidean minimum spanning tree $T$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ made of $n$ nodes $\{V_1, V_2, …, V_n\}$. We know that that each node degree is bounded for any dimension $d$, and the bound is given by the kissing number of the tangent unit spheres.
From this MST, we construct another graph $\mathcal{G}$ using the following procedure. We first delete a node $V_i$, $i=1,...,n$, and construct the Euclidean MST of the remaining $n-1$ nodes. If $V_i$ has degree $K_i$, the new MST will contain $K_i-1$ new edges which link the $K_i$ connected components that are formed after deletion of $V_i$; see e.g. 1. We repeat the same operation for any node $V_i$. Finally, we consider the graph $\mathcal{G}$ made by the original nodes $\{V_1, V_2, …, V_n\}$ and the new edges that are formed at each iteration. To be clear, the edges of $\mathcal{G}$ are all different from the edges of $T$, as the former only includes the new edges that are formed after a node deletion. The number of edges of $\mathcal{G}$ is clearly $\sum_{i=1}^n K_i-1 = n-2$.
Are the degrees of the $\mathcal{G}$ nodes bounded as in the original MST? Monte-Carlo simulations I've made suggest the $\mathcal{G}$ still has bounded degrees, but the bound is larger than that of $T$. Moreover, $G$ is generally disconnected and can have repeated egdes.

The degrees are not necessarily bounded.
Consider the case where $\{V_1, \dots, V_n\}$ are vertices of a nearly-regular $n$-gon in $\mathbb R^2$ - slightly uneven just to avoid ties. If we make the distance between $V_1$ and $V_n$ the longest, then the MST is going to be a path with edges $V_1V_2, V_2V_3, \dots, V_{n-1}V_n$.
When we delete $V_1$ or $V_n$, nothing is added to $\mathcal G$. When we delete any of $V_2, \dots, V_{n-1}$, an edge between $V_1$ and $V_n$ is added to $\mathcal G$, since that's the cheapest way to reconnect the two halves of the path. As a result, $\mathcal G$ just has $n-2$ copies of the same edge, and $V_1$ and $V_n$ both have degree $n-2$ in $\mathcal G$.
